# Merge multiple files into 1 file with a newline character between the contents of each file in command line

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I've got for example 2 files with the contents

**test.txt**

```
1
```

**test2.txt**

```
2
```

I want to merge these 2 files into one file.
I saw on related questions that it was recommended to use

```
type *.txt > merged.txt
```

however this would result in a file with the contents of `12` without a newline character in between which I heard the type command was supposed to do

**edit:**
I solved the problem by modifying Luis's answer and making a batch file and subfolder for the files I want merged

```
@echo off
type nul > merged.txt
FOR /R .\files %%f IN (*) DO (type "%%f" >> merged.txt) && (echo. >> merged.txt)
```

Comment: "would result in a file with the contents of `12` without a newline character in between" -- This exactly shows an advantage of \*nix text files, where there is this requirement that each line (including the last one) shall be terminated with a newline character. Simple concatenation of `1\n` and `2\n` just works, the result is `1\n2\n` and it's again a valid text file ready to be concatenated further (if needed). The design of text files in the Windows world is not that smart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **Windows**, you can use the following command:

```
type test1.txt > merged.txt && echo. >> merged.txt && type test2.txt >> merged.txt
```

I'll explain each part:

1. **type test1.txt > merged.txt** - This command creates a new copy (note the **single >**) of the file named test1.txt with the name *merged.txt*
2. **echo. >> merged.txt** - This command appends (note the **double >>**) a **newline** to the merged file
3. **type test2.txt >> merged.txt** - This command appends the second file at the end of the *merged.txt* file

If you have a number of files that can be represented by a number range, say test1.txt, test2.txt,..., test10.txt, you can try the following alternative:

```
type nul > merged.txt && FOR /L %G IN (1,1,10) DO (type test%G.txt >> merged.txt) && (echo. >> merged.txt)
```

I'll explain each part:

1. **type nul > merged.txt** - creates an empty file named merged.txt
2. **FOR /L %G IN (1,1,10) DO** - Loops for every number between 1 and 10
3. **(type test%G.txt >> merged.txt) && (echo. >> merged.txt)** - the 1st part reads the file and appends it to the merged.txt file. The second part adds a newline once finished.

Comment: I only gave 2 files for ease as an example. Let's say I have 10 files. Is there an easy way in that case or do I need to keep appending newlines with echo 10 times for each in that case? Or do I need to write a batch script in that case?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a case when you have 10 files, named test1, test2, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Since type is an MS DOS, command, you are working on Windows.  I have always used copy

```
copy /a test.txt + test2.txt 3.txt
```

`/a` tells it that they are ASCII files.

The first two are source and the last name is the destination.

If you have newline in your file, it will be copied. It will not manufacture characters on its own.

Comment: While it is a valid command, this doesn't respond the OP question, as it doesn't add a newline between the merged files.

Comment: You could always do this: `echo. > newline.txt` and then `copy /a test.txt + newline.txt + test2.txt 3.txt`

Comment: my instinct is that copy will be faster than type or echo for non-trivial sized files. Not sure though.