# Issue while Concatenating TXT Files

Tags: windows, command-line

I hope you're all doing well.

I have a simple command-line prompt that I use on **Windows** to concatenate all TXT files into one file named "merged."

```
copy *txt merged.txt
```

However, I've encountered an issue where, in the merged file, on the second row, two barcodes are placed next to each other on one line. Ideally, "11073-18216,28" should be on one line, and "11073-6185,12" should be on the next line. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Attached below are 3 txt files for convenience.
Thanks a lot

https://files.fm/u/6pzku5mst4

Comment: The answer is a duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/1827287/367018

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have looked at your files, and this is entirely natural.

You're concatenating as-are files that have no line-endings,
so the first line of the next file gets added to the last
line of the previous text file.

To add a line-ending between files needs code similar to the following:

```
type A01.txt >merged.txt
echo. >>merged.txt
type A03.txt >> merged.txt
echo. >>merged.txt
```

The special command `echo.` will print an empty line,
which is just a line ending, that gets
concatenated to the last line of the last file.

This one-liner entered in the Command Prompt will do it for all
`.txt` files. The result file is stored in the parent folder
(or elsewhere if you wish) to avoid a loop:

```
 FOR %f IN (*.txt) DO type %f >> ..\merged.txt & echo. >> ..\merged.txt
```